Unable to run React native app using expo
When I run npx expo start, It shows the following error:

fetcherror: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/50.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

I tried upgrading my node and npm to the latest version. I also ran the command npm config set strict-ssl false, But none of these worked.

try using sudo npx expo start.
